# Add a fifth value to imrect coordinates

Tags: matlab

I'm using imrect to get the coordinates of a selection in Matlab. Here is the code:

```
figure, imshow(im);
h = imrect(gca);
getPosition(h);
```

What I want is to also add a label (integer) as the fifth element.

So, the output of getPosition(h) is:

```
[7.0000    3.0000    6.0000    9.0000]
```

I want to transform it in:

```
[7.0000    3.0000    6.0000    9.0000    N]
```

where N is a positive integer.

Basically I will have a dropdown menu to select a label, I can do this, but I don't know how to store it in the imrects handler so that in the end when I will save the session (discharge the data to disk) to get also the label not only the coordinates.

Ps. I can do:

```
b = getPosition(h);
b(5) = label();
```

but in my case this doesn't work that well because I need to put it in the structure that imrect creates. The code is much bigger and complex and by doing this I save days in coding than using another variable to do that as in the above example.

Any solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try to create a custom class derived from `imrect`.